# Reverse memory layout for tuple-like class templates

Tags: c++, tuples, template-meta-programming

I'm creating a tuple-like class template using template meta programming.  Unlike a `std::tuple` all of the values in my tuples are the same type, and the number of values is equal to the number of "channel constants" listed in the template parameter list.

Here's an example:

```cpp
enum class Foo { Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 };

MyTuple<float, Foo, Foo::Foo1, Foo::Foo2, Foo::Foo3> good(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
```

This instantiates a variable, good, which contains three floats, and those floats are associated with the corresponding constants from the scoped enum.  Following some tutorials for generic tuples, I came up with an implementation that works for almost all my needs.  The essence of it is:

```cpp
template <typename Rep, typename Space, Space... Channels>
struct MyTuple {};

template <typename Rep, typename Space, Space First, Space... Rest>
struct MyTuple<Rep, Space, First, Rest...> : public MyTuple<Rep, Space, Rest...> {
    using MyBase = MyTuple<Rep, Space, Rest...>;

    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    constexpr MyTuple(Head value, Tail... tail) noexcept :
        MyBase(tail...), m_value(value) {}

    Rep m_value;
};
```

The only drawback is that, if I iterate through the values in memory order, they are returned in the reverse order.  For example, the code below lists `3 2 1` rather than `1 2 3`.

```cpp
auto *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(&good);
std::cout << p[0] << ' ' << p[1] << ' ' << p[2] << '\n';
```

This seems the natural result of the recursive way the tuple is built up.  **Is there a way to get all the same behavior but with the memory order of the values forwards rather than reversed?**

Comment: Why are you doing a `reinterpret_cast` here? If you cared about order you'd wrap `std::vector`. I'm not sure there's any obligation to have any particular memory layout for a tuple.

Comment: @tadman:  I'm want to use MyTuples to specify a "wire format," so how the fields are arrange in memory is important.  That's one of the reasons I'm building my own. 
 The cast was a quick hack to illustrate that the values are arranged in the opposite of the desired order.  A `std::vector` comes with overhead that I'm trying to avoid--I'd eventually like to put MyTuples into a vector or array and have everything contiguous (within alignment constraints).

Comment: You can't trust anything about memory layouts unless the container makes explicit guarantees. If you want to have a wire format, write a serialize and deserialize function pair, like `operator<<` and `operator>>`. Never *presume* a structure will be laid out a certain way. `std::vector` has near zero overhead, and `std::array` even less. Unless you're making a million of these per second you won't notice.

Comment: @tadman:  The standard does give some guarantees.  It's true you cannot control endianness and that there may be padding for alignment.  But I believe my example qualifies as a standard layout type (at least since C++14), which means the relative order of the fields can be known and that you can reinterpret_cast a pointer to MyTuple to a pointer of its Rep type.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make the storage an array?

```
template <typename Rep, typename Space, Space... Channels>
struct MyTuple<Rep, Space, Channels...>
{
    std::array<Rep, sizeof...(Channels)> m_values;
};
```

Comment: I'm definitely exploring `std::array`-based solutions.  In my effort to keep the question  short, I omitted the goal to keep track of the Channels (without  run-time memory overhead).  For example, I'd like to implement `Rep &MyTuple::operator[](Space channel)` to return the value that corresponds to the requested channel.  So far, that's always taken me back to recursive solutions.

Comment: Ah, `sizeof...(Channels)` is a good hint.  I'd forgotten about that particular expansion.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: You can implement a function which gives you the index within the parameter pack of a enumeration value, then you can just index into the array.  That will solve your `operator[]` problem, right?

Comment: Yep.  Thanks!  I just got it working a couple minutes ago in Compiler Explorer.  There were some tricks to ensure it clang, gcc, and MSVC were all happy at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on John Zwinck's suggestions, here's the solution I came up with.

```cpp
template <typename Rep, typename Space, Space... Channels>
class MyTuple2 {
    public:
        static constexpr auto ChannelCount = sizeof...(Channels);
        using Values = std::array<Rep, ChannelCount>;
        MyTuple2(Values values) : m_values(std::move(values)) {}

        constexpr Rep operator[](Space channel) const noexcept {
            return find<0>(channel);
        }

    private:
        static constexpr std::array<Space, ChannelCount> IDs = { Channels... };

        template <std::size_t N>
        constexpr Rep find(Space channel) const noexcept {
            if constexpr (N == ChannelCount) {
                return find_failed();
            } else {
                return (channel == IDs[N]) ? m_values[N] : find<N+1>(channel);
            }
        }

        Rep find_failed() const {
            throw std::domain_error("Requested channel isn't in MyTuple");
        }

        Values m_values;
};
```

The object instance contains only the actual values, stored in-order in a `std::array`.  I retained the channel IDs in a class static `std::array`, which probably isn't strictly necessary, but was simple and acceptable for my use, and it might even be useful in the future.  My tuples contain a very small number of channels, typically 1 to 3 and never more than 32, so the recursion limits are fine and the compilers seem to do a good job optimizing it away.

The termination condition for recursion in template meta-programming is usually a specialization, but it was difficult to apply here in a way that was readable to humans and acceptable to clang, gcc, and MSVC.  Note that the if statement must be `constexpr` and have the alternate path in an explicit else clause to ensure the compilers that the recursion is reasonably bounded.